# Want my while loop to finish and output after I enter a number which is over 800 but it is giving me unhandled exceptions

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

// While Loop & if statement

```
while (userInput < 800)
{
    if (userInput >0 && userInput <200)
    {
        cOne++;
        sumLengthOne = sumLengthOne + userInput;
        userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }  
    else if (userInput >200 && userInput <400)
    {
        cTwo++;
        sumLengthTwo = sumLengthTwo + userInput;
        userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    else if (userInput >400 && userInput <600)
    {
        cThree++;
        sumLengthThree = sumLengthThree + userInput;
        userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    else if (userInput >600 && userInput <800)
    {
        cFour++;
        sumLengthFour = sumLengthFour + userInput;
        userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    else if (userInput > 800)
    {
        break;
    }
}        

Console.WriteLine("| {0,-10} | {1,5} | {6,10} | {11,15} |" , "Range" , "Count" , "Sum Lengths" , "Percentage");
Console.WriteLine("==========");
Console.WriteLine("| {0,-10} | {1,5} | {6,10} | {11,15} |" , "<200" + "200 - 399" + "400 - 599");
Console.WriteLine("The Largest Bacteria Is: " + largestValue);
Console.WriteLine("The Smallest Bacteria Is: " + smallestValue);
```

The unwanted result is unhandled exception
"    Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list"

after the while loop I am outputting the results to console but it gives an unhandled exception instead.

Comment: "*after the while loop I am outputting the results to console*" - this code should be included in the question, as it is the part that triggers the exception

Comment: Code review: when you test for `<200` in the `if`, you don't need to test for `>=200` in the next `else if`. Right now a 200 value falls between the cracks! (same for 400, 600, 800)

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure how your userInput comes into play, from input field or from looping through values. but...

When inputs like 200, 400, 600, 800 are typed, you have no matching condition. you are either above or under 800 but not === 800

you conditions should be something like this:

```html
        while (userInput < 800)
        {
            if (userInput >0 && userInput <= 200) // below or equal too
            {
                cOne++;
                sumLengthOne = sumLengthOne + userInput;
                userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }  
            else if (userInput >200 && userInput <= 400) // below or equal too
            {
                cTwo++;
                sumLengthTwo = sumLengthTwo + userInput;
                userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (userInput >400 && userInput <= 600) // below or equal too
            {
                cThree++;
                sumLengthThree = sumLengthThree + userInput;
                userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (userInput >600 && userInput <= 800) // below or equal too
            {
                cFour++;
                sumLengthFour = sumLengthFour + userInput;
                userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (userInput > 800)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Ofcourse if you want to break 200, 400, 600 & 800 and under you would have to do it the other way around - like this:

```html
        while (userInput < 800)
        {
            if (userInput >= 0 && userInput <200) // 0 or above
            {
                cOne++;
                sumLengthOne = sumLengthOne + userInput;
                userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }  
            else if (userInput >= 200 && userInput <400) // 200 or above
            {
                cTwo++;
                sumLengthTwo = sumLengthTwo + userInput;
                userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (userInput >= 400 && userInput <600) // 400 or above
            {
                cThree++;
                sumLengthThree = sumLengthThree + userInput;
                userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (userInput >= 600 && userInput <800) // 600 or above
            {
                cFour++;
                sumLengthFour = sumLengthFour + userInput;
                userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (userInput >= 800) // 800 or above
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your line

```
Console.WriteLine("| {0,-10} | {1,5} | {6,10} | {11,15} |" , "Range" , "Count" , "Sum Lengths" , "Percentage");
```

That `{6,10}` doesn't mean "from char 6 to 10" but "use argument #6, formatted as 10 chars wide". And you don't have an argument #6 (or #11). You meant index 2 and 3 there.

Fixed:

```
Console.WriteLine("| {0,-10} | {1,5} | {2,10} | {3,15} |" , "Range" , "Count" , "Sum Lengths" , "Percentage");
```

---

Tip: for the following dividing line, use this:

```
Console.WriteLine(new string ('=', 33));
```

to output 33 "=" characters.

Comment: Thanks Hans, this is very helpful.